# Spark Cassandra connector version mismatch

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to connect to a Cassandra DB from my sample SPARK Scala code. But iam running into version mismatch error.
Could some one help me on this ?

**Datastax enterprise version** : 4.8

**Error:**
bad symbolic reference. A signature in CassandraSQLContext.class refers to type DataFrame in package org.apache.spark.sql which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling CassandraSQLContext.class.

**Pom.xml contents:**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.test
    SampleScala
    1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${SPARK_VERSION}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>${SPARK_VERSION}</version>
</dependency> 

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <SPARK_VERSION>1.4.1</SPARK_VERSION>
</properties>
```

Comment: Looks like `spark-sql` is missing from your dependencies.

Comment: my bad overlooked it. thanks it worked now